# combined multilabel feature selections

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, text-classification, feature-selection, multilabel-classification

I tried to combined chi and mutual information feature selection on multilabel text dataset, i am perform combined feature selection based on averaged weights.

```
def accumulate_weights(train_text_bow, train_labels):
            all_weights_chi2 = np.zeros(train_text_bow.shape[1])
            all_weights_mi = np.zeros(train_text_bow.shape[1])
            for label_idx, label in enumerate(self.mlb.classes_):
                label_train_labels = train_labels[:, label_idx]
                label_train_text_bow = train_text_bow
                label_chi2_selector = SelectKBest(chi2, k="all")
                label_mi_selector = SelectKBest(mutual_info_classif, k="all")
                label_chi2_features = label_chi2_selector.fit_transform(label_train_text_bow, label_train_labels)
                label_mi_features = label_mi_selector.fit_transform(label_train_text_bow, label_train_labels)
                all_weights_chi2 += label_chi2_selector.scores_
                all_weights_mi += label_mi_selector.scores_
            all_weights = (all_weights_chi2 + all_weights_mi) / 2
            top_features = np.argsort(-all_weights)[:3000]
            return top_features
```

now how i can  select final subset to my model when i using binary relevance and label powerset